# How to Post a REST from curl using Postman

Tags: java, spring

I am trying add new contacts to Freshsales CRM in my Java Spring MVC Web Application. I have the following curl cammand to add contacts to fresh sales.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token token=sfg999666t673t7t82" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"contact":{"first_name":"James", "last_name":"Sampleton (sample)", "mobile_number":"1-926-555-9503"}}' -X POST "https://domain.freshsales.io/api/contacts"
```

I need to know how I can post this REST from the curl using `POSTMAN.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open Postman
2. [Change method to POST, add url, add Authorization in
   headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRyLl.png)
3. [Add body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P9BO.png)
4. Set format to application/json
5. Hit on Send

Postman documentation for [sending API requests](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests)